# Android parse xml onPostexecute

Tags: java, android, xml

I am novice parsing Xml, I am doing an Android app and I have one question, I want to parse and in onPostExecute only write in a textview the value of KEY_MEDIA, is it possible to do the set text in onPstExecute or I have to do in the main, here is my code, thank you so much.

```
 private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    String id = extras.getString("id");

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(Detail.this);
            dialog.setMessage("Loading detail...");
            dialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            dialog.setCancelable(true);
            dialog.show();
         }

         protected String doInBackground(String... args) {



            XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
            String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML from URL
            Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element


            NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_SONG);


            // looping through all song nodes <song>
            for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
                // creating new HashMap
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value

                if (id.equalsIgnoreCase(parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID))){


                map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
                map.put(KEY_MEDIA, parser.getValue(e, KEY_MEDIA));

                }


                songsList.add(map);

            }
            return xml;


         }


         protected void onPostExecute(String xml) {

              TextView media =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.media);
    *****===> media.setText();




            dialog.dismiss();




         }
    }




   <opinionss>
<opinions>
<id_song>1</id_song>
<media>38.5000</media>
</opiniones>
<opiniones>
<id_song>2</id_song>
<media>23.0000</media>
</opiniones>
<opiniones>
<id_song>3</id_song>
<media>90.0000</media>
</opinions>
</opinionss>
```

Comment: You can do setText in `onPostExecute`. UI Operations can be done in `onPreExecute`,`onProgressUpdate()` and in `onPostExecute`.

Comment: It's much better to use `SAXParser` to parse XML on Mobile devices because it uses less resources and therefore less battery: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-build-a-simple-sax-parser--mobile-9041

Comment: Thank you so so much, and how can I get only the value of KEY_MEDIA to set this value in the text of textview in my example? Thanks

Comment: From what I understand, use the songList to get the appropriate map, and then use the map to get the KEY_ID value.

Comment: any example with code? Thank you friend

Comment: I don't know how it's the specific element that you can retrieve but you can use songList.get().get(KEY_ID) and using it like setText parameter

Comment: I think we would all be able to help you better if you could share the XML and tell us which data from the XML you want to show in the TextView.

Comment: I have edited my question, I want to show media data. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `media.setText((String) map.get(KEY_MEDIA);` in your `onPostExecute()`.

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice where you had map defined. It will need to be defined as a class member of MyTask. Move it before onPreExecute().

Answer (score 0):

You can do UI modifications in onPostExecuted because that method is executed in the UI thread.

The only thing you need to worry about is: that TextView will only be accessible after the activity's onCreate, otherwise you will have a nullPointer Exception

Comment: Thanks, and how can I setText the Textview with the value of KEY_MEDIA in my example? Thank you

Comment: instead of returning the full xml String in the doInBackground you can return the string you're going to use in onPostExecute (return value of doInBackground is the input of onPostExecute)

Answer (score 0):

(From http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

**The 4 steps**

When an asynchronous task is executed, the task goes through 4 steps:

1. onPreExecute(), invoked on the UI thread before the task is executed. This step is normally used to setup the task, for instance by showing a progress bar in the user interface.
2. doInBackground(Params...), invoked on the background thread immediately after onPreExecute() finishes executing. This step is used to perform background computation that can take a long time. The parameters of the asynchronous task are passed to this step. The result of the computation must be returned by this step and will be passed back to the last step. This step can also use publishProgress(Progress...) to publish one or more units of progress. These values are published on the UI thread, in the onProgressUpdate(Progress...) step.
3. onProgressUpdate(Progress...), invoked on the UI thread after a call to publishProgress(Progress...). The timing of the execution is undefined. This method is used to display any form of progress in the user interface while the background computation is still executing. For instance, it can be used to animate a progress bar or show logs in a text field.
4. onPostExecute(Result), invoked on the UI thread after the background computation finishes. The result of the background computation is passed to this step as a parameter.

1, 3 and 4 are all executed on the UI thread.

You can change `doInBackground` to return the `HashMap` and then in `onPostExecute` do what you want with the results

PS change the generic parameters of AsyncTask to `<String, String, HashMap>` if you change the return type of `doInBackground`